# How to create a web-view for iOS/Android?

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, pie-chart, amcharts

I am in the process of creating an interactive pie-chart that works on Android and iOS.
 I have the pie chart in the  `[following link]`[1](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) which works on browser.
Please help me to create a web-view for it that works on both platforms properly.

Comment: Both the OS have their own webview, it can easily render the pie-chart you make, all is needed a an HTML page, and the link to the HTML page to open, or if you want to keep the HTML inside the iOS/Android application you can do that too.

Comment: i am very new to ios , so if you can give me a short example how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can add a WebView using the following code on ios platform:

```
      NSString *fullURL = @"Url";//Replace url with your own html page url
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
      NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
      [self.view addSubview:webView];
```